# Crash when adding space after 4 integers entered into UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a `UITextField` where I'm typing integer values and I'm trying to add a space after 4 characters automatically. It is crashing after 4 integers. I'm getting `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. What is causing this?

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cardNumber.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cardNumberChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}

func cardNumberChanged(sender:UITextField) {

    var enteredNumber = cardNumber.text

    var number = NSNumber(longLong: Int64(enteredNumber.toInt()!))

    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    formatter.groupingSize = 3

    var formattedNumber = formatter.stringFromNumber(number)!

    cardNumber.text = "\(formattedNumber)"
}
```

**Non-author edit**

The console shows:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Crashing on the line that converts the entered text into an integer.

[image]

Comment: Try this  cardNumber?.text = "\(formattedNumber)"

Comment: @Memon is working but not separating. Could you tell how can I separate after 4 intergers

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can solve any problem *

Construct a regular expression to match 4 digits and zero or more optional spaces.

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\d{0,4}) *", options:NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error:nil)
```

And store this in the view controller instance (`NSRegularExpression` objects are expensive to create).

Then you can do a simple replacement of the matched group (the part of the regex surrounded in brackets). This replaces the matched group with itself and a space.

Finally trim any whitespace (this will remove leading/trailing whitespace).

```
if let replacement = regex?.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(enteredText, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, textLength), withTemplate: "$1 ") {
   cardNumber.text = replacement.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
}
```

The full code is as follows:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\d{0,4}) *", options:NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error:nil)

@IBOutlet weak var cardNumber: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cardNumber.addTarget(self, action: Selector("cardNumberChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
}

func cardNumberChanged(sender:UITextField) {

    let enteredText = cardNumber.text
    let textLength = enteredText.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if let replacement = regex?.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(enteredText, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, textLength), withTemplate: "$1 ") {
        cardNumber.text = replacement.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
    }

}
```

Please note that although I'm confident that this answers the original question, it **is not** a fool-proof mechanism for handling credit card number input (if that is indeed what you are trying to achieve) as the user will still be able to enter spaces in arbitrary positions as well as other non-numeric characters, e.g. I can happily enter `"1231 4123 1231 23 1 2 31  -23 1212 32  -  -  a  s  d  a  s d"`.

* not a factual statement